# Last.fm cannot authorize any scrobbling

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, time-zone, last.fm

I have a MacBook-Pro with Mac OS X 10.6.4 install on it. iTunes 9.2.1(5) with Last.fm 1.5.4.26864 (latest update) every thing worked fine until yesterday but today when I open iTunes and Last.fm I get this error:

[alt text http://www.free-imagehosting.com/out.php/i3504_Screenshot20100801at11.23.35AM.png](http://www.free-imagehosting.com/out.php/i3504_Screenshot20100801at11.23.35AM.png)

I set my time zone in last.fm profile setting Asia/Tehran and also set my laptop time automatically and manually and got this error in both setting.

Comment: So both Last.fm and your computer are set to Tehran time, then?

Comment: yes I set my laptop timezone to tehran but still get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve this by set my time zone with my official Time of my country using NTP.

I find the NTP server of my country was ntp.irnic.ir .

[alt text http://www.free-imagehosting.com/out.php/i3950_Screenshot20100813at2.24.39AM.png](http://www.free-imagehosting.com/out.php/i3950_Screenshot20100813at2.24.39AM.png)